# CountDownTime inside Listview

Tags: android, listview, countdowntimer

I am developing one android application and on one screen i have `Listview` with countdown timer on each row. I am using List Adapter. I tried Google and other reference but not getting actual output. I have seconds returned from web-service, I am converting seconds to `hh:mm:ss` format and started countdown timer using `CountdownTimer` class. but when i am scrolling Listview it changes behavior, I know this is the common problem for android `Listview` but i want to display countdown timer on each row with complete moving time second by second.

Please help me friend, Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the getView() method of your custom adapter you should always restart the timer with the time currently left.

Comment: @ÁronNemmondommegavezetéknevem : how can i restrart my timer everytime in adapter?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on how the behavior changes if you scroll the ListView? I think, I got the same problem, but right now can't determine that. My problem is, if you scroll to another item with timer-textview, then the textview of the second one jumps between two times, from the two different running CountDownTimer-instances. Could you post some code of your code in question or if solved, of code with fix?

Comment: @arne.jans : yes i was getting same issue. when i scroll listview it changing behaviour of timer. started 2 times and effecting textviews. but for then i have leave that point in my app.

Answer (score 1):

meh from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193296/updating-text-for-multiple-instances-of-a-textview-from-a-countdowntimer) here gave a good advice.

From within the CountDownTimer, don't update the textviews in the listview-item directly, but update some String in the data-objects from the adapter. **Afterwards let another separate CountDownTimer call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()** to let the listitem-views update themselves. I call this one adapterNotifier in code.

The adapterNotifier alone should call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to avoid the additional overhead if every other single CountDownTimer would itself call adatper.notifyDataSetChanged().

In the getView()-method from the adapter, don't do anything fancy, only read the pre-computed strings from the data-object and update the textviews as usual.

The main drawback to this approach is, that you update the whole of **every** listitem, which could be overkill if you have e.g. network-loaded images in the listitems. I will try to optimize this further.

Here is some code

```
public Adapter(Context context, ListData dataList) {
    super(context, dataList);
    this.dataList = dataList;
    initTimerData(dataList);
}

private void initTimerData(ListData dataList) {
    long longestTimerInterval = 0;
    for (final Data data : dataList) {
        if (data.show_timer) {
            if (data.end_time == null) {
                data.show_timer = false;
                continue;
            }
            long endTimeMillis = 0;
            try {
                endTimeMillis = dataDateTimeProcessor.parse(data.end_time).getTime();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e(DataDetailFragment.class.getSimpleName(), "Error parsing data-time: ", e);
            }

            // TODO use the server-time for reliability
            long nowTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long timeInterval = endTimeMillis - nowTime;

            // if the data is over or more than 24 hours away, don't display the timer
            if (nowTime >= endTimeMillis ||
                timeInterval > 24 * 3600 * 1000) {
                data.show_timer = false;
                continue;
            }

            // save the longest interval for an extra adapter-notifier timer
            if (timeInterval > longestTimerInterval)
                longestTimerInterval = timeInterval;

            // this listener holds the references to the currently visible data-timerviews
            DataCountDownTimerListener timerListener = new DataCountDownTimerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    int seconds = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60);
                    int minutes = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (60000)) % 60);
                    int hours   = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (3600000)) % 24);
                    data.timerSeconds = String.format("%02d", seconds);
                    data.timerMinutes = String.format("%02d", minutes);
                    data.timerHours = String.format("%02d", hours);
                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    data.timerSeconds = "00";
                    data.timerMinutes = "00";
                    data.timerHours = "00";
                }
            };

            if (data.endTimer != null) {
                Utils.stopDataTimer(data);
            }

            data.endTimer = new DataCountDownTimer(timeInterval, 1000);
            data.endTimer.setDataCountDownTimerListener(timerListener);
            data.endTimer.start();
        } else {
            data.show_timer = false;
        }
    }

    initAdapterNotifier(longestTimerInterval);
}

private void initAdapterNotifier(long longestTimerInterval) {
    // no timers here, go away
    if (longestTimerInterval == 0)
        return;

    adapterNotifier = new DataCountDownTimer(longestTimerInterval, 1000);
    DataCountDownTimerListener adapterNotifierListener = new DataCountDownTimerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO evaluate performance
            // update the adapter-dataset for timer-refreshes
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // last timer finished, nothing to do here
        }
    };
    adapterNotifier.setDataCountDownTimerListener(adapterNotifierListener );
    adapterNotifier.start();
}

public void stopDataTimers() {
    if (adapterNotifier != null)
        adapterNotifier.cancel();
    for (Data data : dataList) {
        if (data.endTimer != null) {
            Utils.stopDataTimer(data);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a class that will handle your timer in each row. I mean a reusable class. you already created a class to make your timer then utilize it.In that class, you should be able to monitor your listview item so that the timer will continue to run. you can reference the id of that listitem.

hope it gives you some hint